How to preserve the type of an enum used as a dictionary key when serializing with Newtonsoft.Json?
I have the following enum which I am using as keys in a Dictionary:
public enum SomeEnum
{ 
    One, Two, Three
}

And the following code throws an exception:
Dictionary<Enum, string> map = new Dictionary<Enum, string>()
{ 
   {SomeEnum.One,"1"},
   {SomeEnum.Two,"2"},
   {SomeEnum.Three,"3"}   
};

string mapStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(map, Formatting.None,
   new JsonSerializerSettings() 
   { 
      TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Full
   });

var newMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<Enum, string>>(mapStr);


Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Could not convert string 'One' to dictionary key type 'System.Enum'. Create a TypeConverter to convert from the string to the key type object. Path 'One', line 1, position 7.'

Probably because the serialized JSON does not contain any type definition that hints about the original run time enum type, and seems like using TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling doesn't help either.

You might be trying to shoehorn too much into your deserialization step. There is no direct way to represent the kind of data you're hoping to capture in a JSON object. I'd recommend translating the entire Dictionary it into a more serializable representation (e.g. a list of objects, where each object has a property that maps to your expected enum types and another property with the enum value), and then using some basic LINQ code to translate from that representation back to your dictionary. You might be able to write a custom TypeConverter which does that, but it smells off.

TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling only works for JSON objects and arrays, by adding a "$type" property to objects, and nesting arrays inside an object with a "$type" property.  However, Json.NET serializes .NET dictionaries as JSON objects, with the dictionary key used for the JSON property name -- so there's no possibility to have an additional "$type" property.

You will need to rethink your design, e.g. by serializing your dictionary as an array of key/value pair objects and wrapping the enums in some sort of TypeWrapper like the one from this answer to Deserialize specific enum into system.enum in Json.Net.

Because you actually want a Dictionary<SomeEnum, string>?

@JeremyLakeman no, I have a Dictionary<Enum,string>, but during run time, the keys might be SomeEnum (or any other enum, for that matter...), so JSON should store the enum run time type for each key, I'm just wondering how
